# Sending base64-encoded image results in a corrupt image

Tags: android, json, base64

I'm encoding an image with `Base64.encodeToString`, adding it (among other pieces of data) to a JSON body and sending it to a web service for storage.

My encoding method looks like this:

```
private static String encodeToBase64(Bitmap image) {
  Bitmap immagex = image;
  ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  immagex.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
  byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
  String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
  return imageEncoded;
}
```

I then simply call `.add("encoded_image", encodeToBase64(bitImage));` on the `JSONObject` and send it through my web service class.

However, when I get the image on the other side, it is corrupt. The PHP function `base64_decode` executes and seems to provide an image, but when I write that image to a temp file, I cannot open it. It says the image is corrupt. I'm not really sure where to start looking.

I've looked at other threads, but their solutions don't seem to work.

Help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the `DEFAULT` options mix well with your PHP version.
There appears to be a bug in certain versions on PHP which makes the `base64_decode` bug out if the input is not properly formatted.

Try adding the `NO_WRAP` option, to make sure that there are no whitespace/likebreak characters in the produced output.

If that does not help, have a look at the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-decode.php) page for the `base64_decode` function for hints on how to get it working.

It might also help if you analysed what you send in android and receive in php, i.e. log some debug output or inspect with breakpoints, to see if anything is wrong.

Comment: NO_WRAP actually worked.  It looks like there were linebreaks in the output.  Thanks.